# Python's requests "Missing dependencies for SOCKS support" when using SOCKS5 from Terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, socks, urllib3

I'm trying to interact with an API from my Python 2.7 shell using a package that relies on Python's requests. Thing is the remote address is blocked by my network (university library).

So to speak to the API I do the following:

```
~$ ssh -D 8080 name@myserver.com
```

And then, in new terminal, in local computer:

```
~$ export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Then I run the program in Python console but fails:

```
~$ python
>>> import myscript
>>> id = '1213'
>>> token = 'jd87jd9'
>>> connect(id,token)

File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 518, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 273, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 169, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

This excerpt is from the [adapters.py requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/adapters/):

```
> try:
>     from .packages.urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager except ImportError:
>     def SOCKSProxyManager(*args, **kwargs):
>         raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
```

Now problem seems to be originated in urllib3's SOCKSProxyManager.

So I read you can use SOCKSProxyManager with SOCKS5 if you have install [PySocks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks) or you do a *pip install urllib3[socks]*

Alas, I tried both PySocks and urllib3 with Socks without any success.

Any idea of another workaround?

**EDIT:**

I also tried *pip install requests[socks]* (that's requests 2.10.0 with Socks support) and I am getting this:

```
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-server.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x95c7ccc>: Failed to establish a new connection: SOCKS5 proxy server sent invalid data',))
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I had the same issue with conda and requests 2.11 (I work in a Ubuntu VM behind a corporate proxy).

[This issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3516) helped me. I changed my environment variable `all_proxy` (which was originally set to a SOCK proxy `socks://....`) to the https version in my .bashrc file :

`export all_proxy="https://<proxy>:<port>/"`

and now it works.

Comment: Thanks! I totally ditched working from the library so I can't test. But I trust you!

Comment: but I AM using socks proxy

Comment: Hint for noobs: `echo $all_proxy` to see what your machine is currently set to. It's probably `socks://<proxy>:<port>/`, so all you have to do is replace the prefix.

Comment: either this, or `pip install pysocks`

Comment: this fix it for me.   thanks.  even with all the deps installed, this is the error you will get if the socks://  prefix is used

Answer (score 166):

This means that requests is using socks as a proxy and that socks is not installed.

Just run
`pip install pysocks`

Or install requests via
`pip install "requests[socks]"`

Comment: This works for me, however, we need to close the proxy first to install this module.

Comment: That's the problem, if `pip install` doesn't go through the proxy how am I supposed to install `pysocks`

Comment: Wow, for the second time I face that problem, googling, and reaching your answer which is the solution I always forget :)
If only stackoverflow allows upvoting multi times, I'd upvote this thousand times :)

Comment: TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cert_file'")

Comment: In 2022 This is still the correct answer to the question.

Comment: you can install pysocks using tarball first

Comment: @iopq you can first unset the proxy by `unset all_proxy && unset ALL_PROXY`, then install the `pysocks` and again set the proxy if needed `export all_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari if I unset the proxy I can't connect to the internet

Answer (score 23):

In Ubuntu you can run :
`unset all_proxy && unset ALL_PROXY`

Comment: Well, this disables the proxy, which is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 16):

I added the `requests[socks]>=2.10.0` to my requirements.txt, updated my `https_proxy` env variable, and came across the above error. I then tried a regular `pip install requests[socks]` after resetting the `https_proxy` env variable and `PySocks` was installed. I'm not sure why the `pip install -Ur requirements.txt` failed to install PySocks the first time.

After that, I was able to make a request in python using the socks proxy.

It looks like your socks server is not behaving. I would see if you, or your admin, could watch the logs and see what the machine is complaining about.

Comment: I'll test it your suggestion but as soon as I have the chance. For the moment I decided to work from elsewhere (not from the University). And I'll let you know. For the moment I'll upvote your answer. Thanks, Kirk!

Comment: Yes, this was a non-obvious issue. For some reason, this module was not correctly installed via `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 10):

In debian 10, Python 3:

```
pip3 install pysocks
```

Answer (score 10):

How about using apt-get instead of pip? 
 When I use apt-get, I can ignore proxy settings, so the following works good for me.

Using

```
apt-get update && apt-get install  python-socks
```

Instead of

```
pip install pysocks
```

Comment: This method works well, when I build docker image under setting vpn proxy.

Comment: This is definitely not recommended. This way you are altering the operating system. You either want to use `pip` to install it for the local user only (in their home directory) or in a virtual environment. Polluting the OS will bite you in the long term.

Answer (score 7):

I also stumbled upon this issue while doing a simple `pip install -U pip`, but information I found from your question helped me resolved my issue. I am on Mac OS X.

As you have pointed out, [adapters.py](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/adapters/) from the `requests` package was trying to do this:

```
try:
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager
except ImportError:
    def SOCKSProxyManager(*args, **kwargs):
        raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
```

So it seems sensible to look for the [place of definition of SOCKSProxyManager](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/a019c5e9e8ac461111552fdf9aa97899977cccbf/urllib3/contrib/socks.py). It seems to be in a "contrib" module in urllib3 and not installed alongside urllib3 by default. The docstring of that module says:

```
This module contains provisional support for SOCKS proxies from within
urllib3. This module supports SOCKS4 (specifically the SOCKS4A variant) and
SOCKS5. To enable its functionality, either install PySocks or install this
module with the ``socks`` extra.
```

The instructions of the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) says this about setuptools extras:

```
6. Install a package with setuptools extras.

$ pip install SomePackage[PDF]
$ pip install git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage[PDF]
$ pip install SomePackage[PDF]==3.0
$ pip install -e .[PDF]==3.0  # editable project in current directory
```

So I followed the instructions and did:

```
$ pip install 'urllib3[socks]'
```

I then continued with `pip install -U pip`, which was what I was supposed to be doing, and now it works.

I wonder how many people got tricked-up by the square brackets, as Bash and other shells often treat it as a special character, which needs to be escaped for it to reach the invoked program (in this case, pip).

Comment: Good to know my issue helped you resolve yours. And thankfully yours will solve someone else's issue too!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error just a few mins ago.Then re-installed **request[socks]** via pip.
It seems that there was a missing part of socks which is **win-inet_pton**. Pip installed it and the problem is solved.

Comment: `pip install request[socks]` did NOT work, but `pip install -U requests[socks]` worked

Comment: `-U --upgrade` option alone will not work if you had some previous package installed. `pip install -U requests[socks] --ignore-installed` will work.

Comment: @erm3nda `--force-reinstall` is somewhat cleaner than `--ignore-installed`, as it will clean up a (potentially different) previously installed package first. I use `--ignore-installed` only when I want to locally override a package that is installed system-wide (which can happen inside a virtual env set up with `--system-site-packages`).

Answer (score 4):

You must add socks support with python `requests` library:

```
pip install requests[socks]
```

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, I do the following commands:

```
# Unset socks proxy
unset all_proxy    
unset ALL_PROXY
# Install missing dependencies:
pip install pysocks
# Reset proxy
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue where got the error `Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.` with Anaconda Python 3.7

As `conda` command was working fine, I installed `pysocks` with the command `conda install pysocks`

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just unset your `all_proxy` environment variable, and this should work. Also you can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3516) in github.

On Ubuntu you can use the following command `unset all_proxy` and restart terminal

Comment: Unfortunately I resolved the issue by not going to the library. So I can't give you feedback. But thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

My environment is Ubuntu 16.4 LTS and Python3.5.2
I use pip3 to install libs got the same issue. so I use the command `unset ALL_PROXY` to solve this problem and it works.

PS:
use `printenv | grep -i proxy` to show the proxy info.

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to fix my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I used all the above methods, but only this worked for me:

```
set | grep -i all_proxy
```

it returned:

```
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
```

and then, I did this:

```
export all_proxy=""
```

Finally, it didn't appear mistakes again.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error after a reported issue that `pysocks` would not be pulled by the `requests[socks]>=0.23.0` requirement.

I could (esoterically) fix it by removing the `requests>=0.23.0` requirement i also had in the same `requirements.txt`.

Running Python3.7 on Debian, and the user who reported the bug is running python3.6 on Ubuntu.

### Before the patch

```sh
$ cat requirements.txt 
requests>=2.23.0
requests[socks]>=2.23.0
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
Collecting requests>=2.23.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/1e/0c169c6a5381e241ba7404532c16a21d86ab872c9bed8bdcd4c423954103/requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 202kB/s 
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/f0/a391d1463ebb1b233795cabfc0ef38d3db4442339de68f847026199e69d7/urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 617kB/s 
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.8MB/s 
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 10.4MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/c4/6c4fe722df5343c33226f0b4e0bb042e4dc13483228b4718baf286f86d87/certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 4.7MB/s 
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.10 requests-2.24.0 urllib3-1.25.10
```

### After the patch

Now applying the following patch:

```
diff --git a/sauron/requirements.txt b/sauron/requirements.txt
index a0c901b..f38d18f 100644
--- a/sauron/requirements.txt
+++ b/sauron/requirements.txt
@@ -1,2 +1 @@
-requests>=2.23.0
 requests[socks]>=2.23.0
```

```sh
$ cat requirements.txt 
requests[socks]>=2.23.0
$ cat requirements.txt 
requests[socks]>=2.23.0
(venv) $ pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt 
Collecting requests[socks]>=2.23.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/1e/0c169c6a5381e241ba7404532c16a21d86ab872c9bed8bdcd4c423954103/requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 234kB/s 
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests[socks]>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/f0/a391d1463ebb1b233795cabfc0ef38d3db4442339de68f847026199e69d7/urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 678kB/s 
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests[socks]>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 2.3MB/s 
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests[socks]>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 6.2MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests[socks]>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/c4/6c4fe722df5343c33226f0b4e0bb042e4dc13483228b4718baf286f86d87/certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 4.8MB/s 
Collecting PySocks!=1.5.7,>=1.5.6; extra == "socks" (from requests[socks]>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/59/b4572118e098ac8e46e399a1dd0f2d85403ce8bbaad9ec79373ed6badaf9/PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, chardet, idna, certifi, PySocks, requests
Successfully installed PySocks-1.7.1 certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.10 requests-2.24.0 urllib3-1.25.10
```

Pysocks was effectively pulled.

Answer (score 0):

My fix is:After I unproxy my terminal,the installation is running well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This page shows up for a similar issue under AlmaLinux 8, a pip3 install failing, it was resolved by installing:

sudo dnf install 3proxy
(Tried the Python-based cases above, no success)