# pip install doesnt work , InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support

Tags: python, pip, socks

I am freaking out with this error I am struck on for 2 days. 2 days ago activated my virtualenv, then tried to install some dependencies but pip install keeps throwing this error.

```
pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/blackpython/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

I tried installing request[socks], but then I get an error saying that it cannot make out the socks version

```
printenv | grep -i proxy
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
http_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
all_proxy=socks://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
ALL_PROXY=socks://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
https_proxy=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080/
```

This is proxy setting on my system, can anyone help me with this?
Thanks 
edit: I tired reinstalling ubuntu, and I am still facing this error

Comment: Did you check out the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015/pythons-requests-missing-dependencies-for-socks-support-when-using-socks5-fro

Comment: yes it worked.. i had to set all_proxy as https protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also not able to install Django and other stuffs after activating venv than I finally did this [1]

```
type: sudo gedit .bashrc #or any text editor if gedit is not there 

      add this line at the last of your .bashrc file 
      export all_proxy="https://your_proxy:your_port/"
```

save the changes it should work. Thanks

Ref. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959360/4706745

Answer (score 13):

1. Unset socks proxy, in your case:

   `unset all_proxy
   unset ALL_PROXY`
2. Install missing dependencies:

   `pip install pysocks`
3. Reset proxy, `source .bashrc`, and `pip install` works again with socks proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me `pip  install --user --proxy https://user:pass@proxyaddress:port django`

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall the installed package using

```
pip uninstall packagename
```

and set the proxy

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

and try to install using

```
pip install packagename
```