# Error: No matching distribution found for pip

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am trying to install pip in my **python 2.6.6**, I have **Oracle Linux 6**

I followed the answers given at this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294467/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2-6)

I downloaded **get-pip.py** file and ran the following command

```
sudo python2.6 get-pip.py
```

**However I get the following error**

```
[root@bigdatadev3 Downloads]# sudo python2.6 get-pip.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3cad210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3cadad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3cad6d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3cad790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3cad110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

The error shows some network issue, but I have full open internet access here.

How can I install pip?

I also tried yum, `yum install python-pip` but it gave the following message

```
[root@bigdatadev3 ~]# yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
Setting up Install Process
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**Update 1**:

I used the following command,

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="MY_PROXY"
```

I get the following error

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    Collecting pip
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
        ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
        require_hashes
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
        self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
        all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
        for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
        page = self._get_page(location)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
        return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
        return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
        resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
        proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
        **proxy_kwargs
      File "/tmp/tmpnz7ISh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
        raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
    InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

Comment: Maybe : `DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting pip `

Comment: I can't upgrade my python, I have to live with this. :(

Comment: Are you using a proxy ? sudo will not herit from your current proxy parameters. If so, try that : `python get-pip.py --proxy="[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port"`

Comment: I exported my proxies like this before using sudo `export http_proxy=<MY_PROXY>`, `export https_proxy=<MY_PROXY>`

Comment: That's why it's not working, using sudo will not use those exports.

Comment: what shud I use? yum install gave the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a proxy issue because of using sudo. Starting a command with sudo will not ensure that exports like `export http_proxy=<MY_PROXY>`are still up to date.

You should try that :

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port"
```

and if you don't have user/passwd just :

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="proxy.server:port"
```

**Example :**

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="192.168.0.12:3128"
```

Comment: do I need to provide the proxy in double quotes?

Comment: You shoud look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015/pythons-requests-missing-dependencies-for-socks-support-when-using-socks5-fro

Answer (score 3):

First run cmd as administrator in windows. Then just try `python get-pip.py --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host=pypi.org`. I have tried and it works for me.

Comment: Why do you assume they are running windows when they specifically stated Oracle Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `~/.pip/pip.conf` to this:

```
index-url = https://
trusted-host={my-artifactory-url}
```