# Error while installing python-pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, yum

I'm trying to install Superset (Airbnb Data visualizer) on an equivalent of "PuTTY" installed by the firm I'm working for on a Windows computer, following this tutorial : http://airbnb.io/superset/installation.html

After the first lines (sudo yum install ...) I tried this line :

```
pip install virtualenv
```

And I had:

```
"bash: pip: command not found".
```

I tried the following :

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo yum install python-pip
yum install -y python-pip # after a yum -y update
```

It still doesn't work... I have errors everytime, particularly this one :

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos This system is
receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite. No package
python-pip available. Error: Nothing to do
```

Then I found solutions on the web, I tried this :

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

But I have an error again (Name or service not known).

I absolutely do not know what to do. Do you have an idea to solve this problem ? 
Thank you for your help.

Edit : I found more détails : I use a RedHat Linux 7.2-11

Answer (score 1):

I would try and install pip using the first option [from the Pip page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a proxy issue with that.
It's written : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip.......


So I tried to follow the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238786/error-no-matching-distribution-found-for-pip

But it doesn't work. Do you have another idea please ?