# not able to 'pip install' matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

When I run `pip install matplotlib` or `pip3 install matplotlib` from my terminal, I get the following error. Can someone tell me why this is happening? I use ubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance.

```
Collecting matplotlib
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/surya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

Comment: I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015/pythons-requests-missing-dependencies-for-socks-support-when-using-socks5-fro)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015) same question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's requests "Missing dependencies for SOCKS support" when using SOCKS5 from Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794015/pythons-requests-missing-dependencies-for-socks-support-when-using-socks5-fro)